# comparison of eigenvalue of solution of Riccati equation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to understand the lecture notes comparison theorems in Riemannian geometry of Eschenburg and have a problem about the proof of Rauch I. Let $E$ be an euclidean vector space and $S(E)$ the space of its self adjoint endomorphisms with a partial ordering by putting $ A \leq B $ if $ \langle Ax,x\rangle \leq \langle Bx,x\rangle , \forall x \in E$.

If $A_{i}: [0, t_{i}) ,\  i = 1, 2 $ are solutions of the Riccati equations $ A_{i} ' + A^2 _{i} + R_{i} = 0 $ with $ \lambda_{-} (R_{1} )\geq \lambda_{+} (R_{2} ) $, $ \lambda_{-}  $ the lowest eigenvalue and $  \lambda_{+}  $ the highest eigenvalue of the self adjoint operator $ R_{i}$, such that $ U := A_{2} -A_{1}  $ has a
continuous extension to $  0$ with $U(0) \geq 0 $. Why does it hold that $ \lambda_{+} (A_{1} (t)) \leq \lambda_{-} (A_{2}(t)) $ on $ (0, t_{0} ) $?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical proof can be found here:

*H. L. Royden*, MR 948079 [**Comparison theorems for the matrix Riccati equation**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160410512), *Comm. Pure Appl. Math.* **41** (1988), no. 5, 739--746.

Actually, more general version of this statement holds for more general version of the matrix Riccati equation. A self-contained and perhaps shorter proof, including your case, can be found in Appendix A (Thms. 38 and 40) of

*D. Barilari, L. Rizzi*, MR3491778 [**Comparison theorems for conjugate points in sub-Riemannian
              geometry**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/cocv/2015013), *ESAIM Control Optim. Calc. Var.* **22** (2016), no. 2, 439--472.